# How to Deserialize complex JSON and create it as C# Object

Tags: c#, json, .net, parsing, json.net

I have a JSON which looks like as follows :

```
{
    "Values": [
        {
            "MsgSource": null,
            "TagName": "Data.New_MSG",
            "RawValue": "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": 145,\r\n    \"StationNo\": 6,\r\n    \"RunTime\": 1800,\r\n    \"ControllerID\": 4,\r\n    \"ControllerAddress\": 2,\r\n    \"ProgramNo\": 2,\r\n    \"ModeID\": \"AutoProgram\",\r\n    \"EventDate\": \"2022-04-27T23:30:02\",\r\n    \"Description\": \"Irrigation Completed\",\r\n    \"MessageCode\": 5\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": 144,\r\n    \"StationNo\": 18,\r\n    \"RunTime\": 1800,\r\n    \"ControllerID\": 4,\r\n    \"ControllerAddress\": 2,\r\n    \"ProgramNo\": 5,\r\n    \"ModeID\": \"AutoProgram\",\r\n    \"EventDate\": \"2022-04-27T22:00:00\",\r\n    \"Description\": \"Irrigation Completed\",\r\n    \"MessageCode\": 5\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": 143,\r\n    \"StationNo\": 15,\r\n    \"RunTime\": 1800,\r\n    \"ControllerID\": 4,\r\n    \"ControllerAddress\": 2,\r\n    \"ProgramNo\": 4,\r\n    \"ModeID\": \"AutoProgram\",\r\n    \"EventDate\": \"2022-04-27T22:00:02\",\r\n    \"Description\": \"Irrigation Completed\",\r\n    \"MessageCode\": 5\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": 142,\r\n    \"StationNo\": 19,\r\n    \"RunTime\": 1800,\r\n    \"ControllerID\": 4,\r\n    \"ControllerAddress\": 2,\r\n    \"ProgramNo\": 5,\r\n    \"ModeID\": \"AutoProgram\",\r\n    \"EventDate\": \"2022-04-27T22:30:02\",\r\n    \"Description\": \"Irrigation Completed\",\r\n    \"MessageCode\": 5\r\n  }\r\n]",
            "ScaledValue": "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": 145,\r\n    \"StationNo\": 6,\r\n    \"RunTime\": 1800,\r\n    \"ControllerID\": 4,\r\n    \"ControllerAddress\": 2,\r\n    \"ProgramNo\": 2,\r\n    \"ModeID\": \"AutoProgram\",\r\n    \"EventDate\": \"2022-04-27T23:30:02\",\r\n    \"Description\": \"Irrigation Completed\",\r\n    \"MessageCode\": 5\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": 144,\r\n    \"StationNo\": 18,\r\n    \"RunTime\": 1800,\r\n    \"ControllerID\": 4,\r\n    \"ControllerAddress\": 2,\r\n    \"ProgramNo\": 5,\r\n    \"ModeID\": \"AutoProgram\",\r\n    \"EventDate\": \"2022-04-27T22:00:00\",\r\n    \"Description\": \"Irrigation Completed\",\r\n    \"MessageCode\": 5\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": 143,\r\n    \"StationNo\": 15,\r\n    \"RunTime\": 1800,\r\n    \"ControllerID\": 4,\r\n    \"ControllerAddress\": 2,\r\n    \"ProgramNo\": 4,\r\n    \"ModeID\": \"AutoProgram\",\r\n    \"EventDate\": \"2022-04-27T22:00:02\",\r\n    \"Description\": \"Irrigation Completed\",\r\n    \"MessageCode\": 5\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": 142,\r\n    \"StationNo\": 19,\r\n    \"RunTime\": 1800,\r\n    \"ControllerID\": 4,\r\n    \"ControllerAddress\": 2,\r\n    \"ProgramNo\": 5,\r\n    \"ModeID\": \"AutoProgram\",\r\n    \"EventDate\": \"2022-04-27T22:30:02\",\r\n    \"Description\": \"Irrigation Completed\",\r\n    \"MessageCode\": 5\r\n  }\r\n]",
            "Status": "Normal",
            "ComStatus": null,
            "TimeStamp": "2022-04-28 13:17:39.851"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I deserialize this JSON and create a List which contains only values from inside RawValue where each payload inside it will behave as a single element in the list. Also how to remove unwanted \r\n and escaping characters from each element in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got JSON containing JSON, basically - so you should *expect* to have to deserialize once. (If you can change the structure of the JSON to avoid this double-serialization, that would be better, admittedly, but I'll assume that's fixed.)

For example, you could have:

```
public class Root
{
    public List<Value> Values { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    // Add other properties if you need them
    public string RawValue { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```cs
string json = ...;
Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
// This just takes the first value - we don't know whether you actually
// ever have more than one...
string rawValue = root.Values[0].RawValue;
JArray array = JArray.Parse(rawValue);
```

That assumes you're happy using `JArray`/`JObject` for the "embedded" objects. If you want to model those as well, you'd have:

```cs
public class Station
{
    [JsonProperty("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StationNo { get; set; }
    // etc
}
```

... then for deserializing:

```cs
string json = ...;
Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
// This just takes the first value - we don't know whether you actually
// ever have more than one...
string rawValue = root.Values[0].RawValue;
List<Station> stations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Station>>(rawValue);
```

There shouldn't be any "extra" escaping by the time you've deserialized twice.

Comment: Actually Values will only have one Value in this case. The only useful data resides inside RawValue. I'm happy with dicts inside RawValue. If you don't mind can you edit your answer and show me how this code would actually look like when put altogether. I'm from Python background and was asked to do this integration in C# out of nowhere with limited time constraint. I'm little confused which block of code will go where.

Comment: @saurabh: I've provided all the code already. It sounds like you only need the first half of the answer. You'd put the classes anywhere you'd like, and the deserialization code "wherever you've got the JSON".

Comment: If that's the case then I guess with little research I'd be able to put it together and it would't be that difficult. Thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
List<RawValue> rawValue= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RawValue>>( 
                       (string) JObject.Parse(json)["Values"]
                       .SelectMany(x =>((JObject) x).Properties()
                       .Where(x=>x.Name=="RawValue")).First()
                       .Value);
```

result (in json format)

```
[{"ID":145,"StationNo":6,"RunTime":1800,"ControllerID":4,"ControllerAddress":2,"ProgramNo":2,"ModeID":"AutoProgram","EventDate":"2022-04-27T23:30:02","Description":"Irrigation Completed","MessageCode":5},
{"ID":144,"StationNo":18,"RunTime":1800,"ControllerID":4,"ControllerAddress":2,"ProgramNo":5,"ModeID":"AutoProgram","EventDate":"2022-04-27T22:00:00","Description":"Irrigation Completed","MessageCode":5},
{"ID":143,"StationNo":15,"RunTime":1800,"ControllerID":4,"ControllerAddress":2,"ProgramNo":4,"ModeID":"AutoProgram","EventDate":"2022-04-27T22:00:02","Description":"Irrigation Completed","MessageCode":5},
{"ID":142,"StationNo":19,"RunTime":1800,"ControllerID":4,"ControllerAddress":2,"ProgramNo":5,"ModeID":"AutoProgram","EventDate":"2022-04-27T22:30:02","Description":"Irrigation Completed","MessageCode":5}]
```

class

```
public class RawValue
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int StationNo { get; set; }
    public int RunTime { get; set; }
    public int ControllerID { get; set; }
    public int ControllerAddress { get; set; }
    public int ProgramNo { get; set; }
    public string ModeID { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int MessageCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: My question might have been confusing but I just want elements present in RawValue as a whole and not individual keys inside them.

Comment: @saurabh What do you mean as a whole?  can you post the result you are expecting?

Comment: Sure, although the answer given by Jon Skeet already satisfies my requirement. If you want to come up with a different approach the expected result should be : ```{
  "ID": 145,      
  "StationNo": 6, 
  "RunTime": 1800,
  "ControllerID": 4,
  "ControllerAddress": 2,
  "ProgramNo": 2,
  "ModeID": "AutoProgram",
  "EventDate": "2022-04-27T23:30:02",
  "Description": "Irrigation Completed",
  "MessageCode": 5
} {next dict} {next dict}
....... and so on
```